# Comparing > 2000 means in SPSS

Tags: spss, mean

I have two Variables containing hourly mean temperatures in SPSS. I'd like to **compare the means for each hour (not the mean of the variable)** for statistically significant differences, but I don't know what statistical test is appropriate. The data is not normally distributed.

There are lots of duplicate cases here as a result of aggregating previously sub-hourly DateTimes. Therefore each Mean temp is a mean of about 3 the cases that were aggregated into the hourly DateTimes.

ANOVA would no be appropriate as this seems to compare the groups (groups being each hour) ***within*** each variable rather than the variables to each other.

Suggestions and advice would be very much appreciated - I expect this is a very elementary problem to an expert.

I am happy to use SPSS Syntax if required.

[image]

Comment: Instead of comparing means at each time point, it seems like you have two time series and want to compare, perhaps, trajectories? I’m not following your aggregation comment, but you can also nest observations within time points if you have multiple observations from one hour. A time series analysis will be necessary due to things like autocorrelation. I’m not sure if this is possible in SPSS, but there are many R packages for time series.

Comment: Thanks mark, I'm looking to be able to accept or reject a hypothesis such as "In this hour, Room 1 was significantly warmer than Room 2". Does that clarify my objective a little? I appreciate your help!

Comment: So you only want to know for every time point (=hour) if there is a significant difference between temp. 1 and temp. 2? 

I also do not follow the aggregation comment.

Comment: Yes that's spot on. Sorry for the confusion here. Take cases 172-177 as an example. They currently all have the same Date time and Temp1/2 values. This is because there were previously 6 temperature readings within an hour long period, the mean of these readings was taken and assigned to a Date time value to represent the whole hour. I haven't removed the duplicate cases that resulted from this operation yet.